# Mac Popup Menu Bar Application

Tags: xcode, macos, asihttprequest

I downloaded this project (https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup) and tried to implement the ASIHTTPRequest framework but it didn't work.
Because Popup is using ARC I disabled it for the ASI Classes.

It says linker command failed and it seems there is a framework missing but I did it the same way I always do and added all required frameworks.

Can somebody of you implement ASIHTTPRequest to the Popup framework or send me a similar popup project?

Thanks for the help!